# How to store JSON into mongodb with python?

Tags: python, mongodb

Say I have a json object in variable **`somejson`** (a dictionary). I have a `myjson` object declared like this:

```
myjson['a'] = 'valueofa'
myjson['b'] = 'valueofb'
myjson['c'] = somejson
```

I want to take this `myjson` object and insert it into `mongodb`. How do I accomplish this? I read that mongoengine is preferred over `pymongo`, but everything I see on `mongoengine` appears to have great emphasis on **documents** and nothing to do with existing `json`. Please shed some light through some sample code or shed some light on what is the best way to insert my `myjson` object into `mongodb`, and be able to retrieve it. Is `mongoengine` the best way to accomplish what I am looking for? Or is it `pymongo` that is better for this case?

I think it should be very simple, but have not found anything that really does a good job explaining what has to be done.

I have looked at the following tutorial:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-flask-mongoengine/

Under the **Define the Schema** section, it talks about a lot of document heavy information to prepare the structure, but nothing about getting existing an existing JSON structure into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use mongoengine, you can store your dictionary in [DictField](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.DictField), for example, or unpack it to [DynamicDocument](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.DynamicDocument). And you always will be able to retrieve it.

In `pymongo` your can just store your dict to document without schema, in your case because [bson](http://bsonspec.org/) supports all json types. And it will be like subdocument in document.